# Resolve "stuck" system process of dropping indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, nonclustered-index

I am re-vamping some indexes, and have decided to drop 3 on a certain table. The process has been running for almost 2 hours now. The table does have quite a few million rows, but I still feel that is a little excessive.

I am new to this, so I had to do some research and came across the SP_WHO2 command, which shows me this:

[image: SP_WHO2 Results]

However, I am having trouble finding out how to resolve the issue of getting those indexes dropped. Should I just cancel and try again? Will that harm anything? Is there a better way?

Thank you for your time

UPDATE: I now also see the below. I see a little more info on what is happening, but still not sure the best way to resolve. I am having trouble finding resources on how to interpret SP_WHO2 results.

[image]

Comment: You are dropping indexes, but why the command is UPDATE STATSTICS ? Better to use sp_WHOISACTIVE.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll look into that command.

Comment: Your drop index is blocked by update stats possibly. You have to kill one .. And preferably drop index when there is less activity on server.

Comment: I do see that the Drop Index is being blocked by the UPDATE STATISTIC. I assumed there was something wrong/stuck, but I infer from your comment that it is just server load and I should wait--nothing is "stuck"?

Comment: From the screenshots it does... 58 spid is for update stats and 162 is drop index.

Comment: I think what I mean was that eventually it would work itself out. I do not see the UPDATE STATISTICS being blocked by anything, but I do not know really what the "SUSPENDED" Status means is happening behind the scenes. Anyways, thanks!